Deactivate Thunar's typing search
I have two folders named "Movies" and "Music" for example. In other file managers like "Dolphin," when I press M twice on my keyboard, it selects "Movies" folder and then the "Music" folder.
But in Thunar, it "types" as I press the buttons. It SEARCHES for the names. If I press M twice, it writes "MM" (bottom-right of the window) instead of selecting the "Music" folder. I have to type "Mu" to select the "Music" folder. Or when I write M and press right arrow (→), I want Thunar to change the selected folder but it moves the blinking typing cursor!
How do I fix it?
I have also found out that I can add some values to xfce4-settings-editor and I think there is a value associated to this feature. I'll appreciate any help.

If you want "Movies", press "MO". If you want "Music", hit "MU".

@vanadium Thanks man, but it's not about MO and MU. It's about using arrow keys while searching for a file. Imagine I have 10 songs from one singer. I can simply use arrow keys instead of typing the whole "singer - hisLongSongName"!

@vanadium Yes, when I type something like "M", a textedit type thing opens and starts writing. So when I press for example the left arrow key, the cursor (in the search textedit) goes left not the selected folder.
But in file managers like dolphin, when I write M, no texedit thing opens so when I press left arrow key it actually goes to the left of the selected file.

Down or up arrow may select the next file in the list. Anyway, this is not something you will be able to change: this behavior is hardcoded. If it is a valid issue, it should be filed with the developers so they can correct it.

@vanadium How do I share this feature with the developers?

Typically, open source projects have a portal on which users can file issues.
